# Why my code runs up to point A and crashes when I give B coordinates?

Tags: c, pointers

I am new at C pointers and I'm trying to find the error.
Any help is appreciated.
The code compiles without any errors. When it runs, it accepts point A coordinates but crashes when I input B coordinates.
The output I get is this:

```
Give Coordinates...
Give A(x1,y1): 
2
3
Give B(x2,y2): 
4
zsh: bus error  ./a.out
andreas@Andreas %
```

Code:

````
#include <stdlib.h>

struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct triangle
{
    struct point *A;
    struct point *B;
    struct point *C;
};

void initialiseTriangle(struct triangle *);

int main()
{
    system("clear");

    struct triangle triangle1, *trianglePtr;
    trianglePtr = &triangle1;
    
    initialiseTriangle(trianglePtr);
    return 0;
}

void initialiseTriangle(struct triangle *object)
{
    printf("Give Coordinates...\n");
    printf("Give A(x1,y1): \n");
    scanf("%d", &object->A->x);
    scanf("%d", &object->A->y);

    printf("Give B(x2,y2): \n");
    scanf("%d", &object->B->x);
    scanf("%d", &object->B->y);

    printf("Give C(x3,y3): \n");
    scanf("%d", &object->C->x);
    scanf("%d", &object->C->y);
}```>quote
````

Comment: Your `struct` has 3 pointers, you don't initialize any of them. Accessing them invokes *undefined behavior* (which just happens to only crash when you access `object->B`)

Comment: The obvious question would be why you declared `A`, `B` and `C` to be pointers instead of directly `struct point` objects

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. Firstly I did what you ask (declared A, B and C to be pointers) and it worked. I was then just experimenting only with pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you allocate space for the triangle, but not for the `point` pointers.

You could either allocate memory (here on the stack) :

```
int main()
{
    system("clear");

    struct triangle triangle1, *trianglePtr;
    struct point pointA, pointB, pointC;
    triangle1.A = &pointA;
    triangle1.B = &pointB;
    triangle1.C = &pointC;
    trianglePtr = &triangle1;
    
    initialiseTriangle(trianglePtr);
    return 0;
}
```

or directly put the `point` structs into the `triangle` struct, instead of using pointers :

```
struct triangle
{
    struct point A;
    struct point B;
    struct point C;
};
```